# How to match two html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example, I have

`<div class="welcome_font"><a href="link" style="color:#5AC7E6;">name</a></div>`

and

`<div id="nameho" style="color:#5AC7E6;">another-name</div>`

I want to write an "if" statement in jquery/javascript where if "name" matches "another-name", then do something. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
var name_1 = $('.welcome_font').text();
var name_2 = $('#nameho').text();

if(name_1===name_2) {
    alert('yes');
} else {
    alert('no');
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/TSGqC/

or

```
var name_check = ($('.welcome_font').text()===$('#nameho').text()?true:false);

if(name_check) {
    alert('yes');
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/TSGqC/1/

Answer (score 0):

The `.html()` function grabs the inner html when using jQuery. So you could use the following to compare the two:

```
if ( $('.welcome_font a').first().html() === $('#nameho').html() )
{
  ...
}
```

let me know if that makes sense or if you have any questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
if( $('.welcome_font a').text() == $('#nameho').text() )
{
////Do something
}
```

Research first next time. You could get this with a simple search.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(".welcome_font a").text() == $("#nameho").text())
{
     //To do
}
```